# To solve a combinatorics question of a system of $n$ friends using invariance

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math, invariance

**Q**. There are $n$ people at a party. Prove that there are two people such that, of the remaining $n-2$ people, there are at least $\lfloor{\frac{n}{2}}\rfloor-1$ of them, each of whom either knows both or else knows neither of the two. Here, "knowing" is a symmetric relation and $\lfloor{x}\rfloor$ denotes the greatest integer function.

I am aware of a solution that utilises Pigeonhole Principle to solve the problem. However, I was wondering whether there existed a way to solve this question using invariance, as usually in systems such as these, there is usually one key aspect that is invariant and which solves the problem easily.

This is just a thought. If anyone knows any resources that might help or provide a proof itself, it would be a great help. Thanks a lot :). By the way, this problem appeared in USAMO 1985/4

Comment: There is a pigeonhole type answer at https://prase.cz/kalva/usa/usoln/usol854.html

Comment: The standard invariance matrix approach works for this - just count row pairs of 1-1 or 0-0. (Kalva's solution counts pairs of 1-0, which is an equivalent approach). I don't think there's a simple invariance approach. At the most, there could be a mono-variance approach, which uses ideas from above.